# What is the best way to read a lot of files simultaneously in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have a multicore processor (for instance, 8 cores) and I want read a lot of files by function `int read_file(...)` and do it using all cores effectively. Also, after executing `read_file` the returned value should be placed in some place (may be in `vector` or `queue`).
I'm thinking about using `async` (from С++11) and `future` (for getting result from `read_file`) with launch policy `launch::async` in a for loop over all files. But it creates a lot of threads during the execution and reading some files can be failed. Maybe I should use some guard on an amount of threads which are created during this execution?

Comment: Reading multiple files simultaneously wouldn't be as effective as you may think, especially using conventional HDDs, since the needle, on the HDD, would need to jump-around to multiple location, while reading, in-between reads done by multiple threads (and in general, your hard drive would be bottleneck, always, opposed to the CPU). Because of that, one could argue that reading the same lot of files in a single thread, sequentially, may be faster. Note: I haven't done any benchmarks, but it's general trend I noticed when launching several file copy jobs.

Comment: The problem is that files are written to the hard drive as a serial stream of bits.  So to read multiple files, that are on the same platter, you would need multiple heads.  Also, if the files were on different platters, your HD would need to support parallel streams.  Next, the interface between the HD and your PC would need to support parallel streams.  Unless everything between your program and the hard drive supports parallelism, you can't read files simultaneously.

Answer (score 4):

Reading files isn't CPU intensive. So you're focusing on the wrong thing. It's like asking how to use all the power of your car's engine effectively if you're going across the street.

Comment: Does this change with solid state drives (not needing to physically move the read head), or does the memory transfer bottleneck still dwarf the CPU operations?

Comment: @SteveO Optimization strategies do change for SSDs, but it's still not going to be CPU intensive.

Comment: @SteveO Even with SSD's, the read speed is still magnitudes slower than the CPU operations. Broadly speaking, it's useful to think of HD speeds as HDD reads take orders of "Milliseconds", SSD reads take orders of "Microseconds", and Memory operations take orders of "Nanoseconds". It's very unlikely that any SSD or HDD operations will be fast enough that multithreading dramatically improves the performance.

Comment: @Xirema: https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832 "Latency numbers every programmer should know".  L1 cache 1ns, main memory 100ns, SSD 150µs. harddrive ~1-10ms (depending on head position).  The important point is that main memory is **slow**.

Answer (score 1):

I've written code and done benchmark study to do exactly that. The storage sub-system configurations vary. E.g. someone may have files spread out into multiple disks, or on the same RAID device consisting of multiple disks. The best solution in my opinion is a combination of a powerful thread pool together with async I/O, that are tailored for the system configuration. For instance, the number of threads in the thread pool can be equal to the number of hardware threads; the number of boost::io_service objects can be equal to the number of disks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm tempted to argue a [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) solution might be ideal.

The basic idea involves creating a thread pool that waits for tasks to arrive and queuing all your file reads into that pool.

```
boost::asio::io_service service;
//The work_ptr object keeps the calls to io_service.run() from returning immediately. 
//We could get rid of the object by queuing the tasks before we construct the threads.
//The method presented here is (probably) faster, however.
std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> work_ptr = std::make_unique<boost::asio::io_service::work>(service);

std::vector<YOUR_FILE_TYPE> files = /*...*/;

//Our Thread Pool
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
//std::thread::hardware_concurrency() gets us the number of logical CPU cores.
//May be twice the number of physical cores, due to Hyperthreading/similar tech
for(unsigned int thread = 0; thread < std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); thread++) {
    threads.emplace_back([&]{service.run();});
}

//The basic functionality: We "post" tasks to the io_service.
std::vector<int> ret_vals;
ret_vals.resize(files.size());
for(size_t index = 0; index < files.size(); index++) {
    service.post([&files, &ret_vals, index]{ret_vals[index] = read_file(files[index], /*...*/);});
}

work_ptr.reset();
for(auto & thread : threads) {
    thread.join();
}

//At this time, all ret_vals values have been filled.
/*...*/
```

One important caveat though: Reading from the disk is orders of magnitude slower than reading from memory. The solution I've provided will scale to virtually any number of threads, but there's very little reason to believe that multithreading will improve the performance of this task, since you'll almost certainly be I/O-bottlenecked, especially if your storage medium is a traditional hard disk, rather than a Solid State Drive.

That isn't to say this is automatically a bad idea; after all, if your `read_file` function involves a lot of *processing* of the data (not just reading it) then the performance gains could be quite real. But I do suspect that your use case is a "Premature Optimization" situation, which is the deathknell of programming productivity.

Answer (score 1):

Async IO is usually done through an event based solution.  You can use `boost::asio`, `libevent`, `libuv` etc.